# Long image list in forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, itemrenderer, listadapter

I am trying to populate a large horizontal list with small images.
There may be thousands of these images that need to be scrolled through.
I want to avoid pagination as the non-fluid motion can make distinguishing your position in the list tricky.

I know iOS, Android and Flex have "List Renderer" patterns. How is the best way to accomplish this in Windows Forms?

The list items aren't going to be of uniform sizes. But the size is predicatable without loading the control.
Ie. I can dictate how wide the whole list is going to be, without loading the entire list.

Comment: May be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303195/winforms-accordion

Comment: Can you explain what "pagination" means in reference to a scrollable list?  Also, can you explain what the "List Renderer" pattern is?

Comment: In Android, Flex and iOS. You produce a class to handle drawing of individual items based on objects in an array. The list control then calls this factory class with a data item whenever a list item is required. This means controls are I ly drawn when required.

Comment: When I say pagination, I simply mean displaying a set number of list items that are jogged by clicking left/right buttons. Instead of a scroll bar.