# Accordion in Windows Form C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, accordion

I'm new in c#,  I'd like to learn if I can using Accordion in Windows form like HTML + JQuery

I know it is possible in HTML off course, but I have to create it on my application windows form, but I don't know how to do it

Somebody knows how to help me ?

Comment: Winforms is outdated.... But yes this is possible. After using "Google" I was able to find this was the first link provided: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/416521/Easy-WinForms-Accordion-Control

Comment: @HighCore: Recommended by the ones who produce WPF. Never to forget that ;)

Comment: winforms is fine: WPF is waaaay too complicated - an opposing viewpoint. There are many accordion controls for winforms.

Comment: How Can I do it please ?

Comment: Guys,  Can I use something instead of Windows Forms to make a Desktop Application ?  Very easy with same results ?

Comment: @Joab you can use WPF, which is the replacement of winforms. It's a much better, modern, rich UI technology. Ignore those who tell you that it's "too complicated". There's no such thing. Those people have an age old mentality and can't understand a declarative language and a proper separation of concerns. Use WPF, you will be able to create rich, responsive, animated, resolution independent, hardware accelerated UIs. Use winforms and you will be able to create boring, slow, gray UIs writing much more code, and having to do ugly hacks for simple things, which can't be ported to other platforms.

Comment: @Joab - google for "winforms accordion control" you will find several - some free, some paid - ie http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/416521/Easy-WinForms-Accordion-Control

Comment: @HighCore Thank you !

Comment: possible duplicate of [winforms accordion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303195/winforms-accordion)

Comment: @pm100 if you believe that *"WPF is too complicated"* and that winforms is somehow "simpler", please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32169375/cross-tabular-data-binding-in-wpf) and compare the winforms based solution which requires reflection and a lot of ugly code with my WPF based solution which is just simple simple properties and DataBinding. Now please try to tell me that "winforms is fine" and "WPF is too complicated", please.

Comment: @TaW yup I agree